# weird behaivior of a js function to remove and add a class in mobile while the struncutre is basiaclly the same

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I want on the click event to remove the class active form the current element and move it the clicked one. I wrote the following code and in the desktop mode it work just fine but in the mobile version it doesn't remove the class from the "old active" element BUT if I click on the already active element the behaviour of my function goes back to normal.

HTML

```
<header>
<!-- the ul in the is visible untill 1200px, after that the "mobile-mene" make visibile a hamburger icon and the "menu" is invisible untill the hamburger is clicked -->
    <nav>
        <a href="#home">
            <span class="logo">
                Ernesto Dovizioso
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <a href="#home"><li class="active">home</li></a>
            <a href="#chisono"><li>chi sono</li></a>
            <a href="#servizi"><li>servizi</li></a>
            <a href="#gallery"><li>galleria</li></a>
            <a href="#contatti"><li>contatti</li></a>
        </ul>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- this is invisible untill the hb menu il clicked -->
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#home"><li class="active">home</li></a>
            <a href="#chisono"><li>chi sono</li></a>
            <a href="#servizi"><li>servizi</li></a>
            <a href="#gallery"><li>galleria</li></a>
            <a href="#contatti"><li>contatti</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

JS

```
const ul = document.querySelectorAll("header ul li");
ul.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener("click", activeLiChange);
});

function activeLiChange(){
    let activeLi = document.querySelector("li.active");

console.log(this.innerHTML);
console.log(activeLi.innerHTML);

if(!this.isEqualNode(activeLi)){
    this.classList.add("active");
    activeLi.classList.remove("active");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't working on mobile is because you are using `querySelector` which only returns the first instance of `.active` which is in your non-mobile menu. You'll need to use `querySelectorAll('li.active')` and iterate over the resulting NodeList.

Using your code as is here is a fix:

```js
const ul = document.querySelectorAll("header ul li");
ul.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener("click", activeLiChange);
});

function activeLiChange(){
  const activeLi = document.querySelectorAll("li.active");

  activeLi.forEach(li => {
    if(!this.isEqualNode(li)){
        this.classList.add("active");
        li.classList.remove("active")
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
        <a href="#home">
            <span class="logo">
                Ernesto Dovizioso
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <a href="#home"><li class="active">home</li></a>
            <a href="#chisono"><li>chi sono</li></a>
            <a href="#servizi"><li>servizi</li></a>
            <a href="#gallery"><li>galleria</li></a>
            <a href="#contatti"><li>contatti</li></a>
        </ul>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- this is invisible untill the hb menu il clicked -->
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#home"><li class="active">home</li></a>
            <a href="#chisono"><li>chi sono</li></a>
            <a href="#servizi"><li>servizi</li></a>
            <a href="#gallery"><li>galleria</li></a>
            <a href="#contatti"><li>contatti</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

But you can simplify this by attaching the listener to each `ul` element instead of every `li`. Then in your `activeLiChange()` function use `target` (the `li`) and `currentTarget` (the `ul`) to address the relevant menu list.

```js
const ul = document.querySelectorAll("header ul");
ul.forEach(list => {
    list.addEventListener("click", activeLiChange);
});

function activeLiChange(e){
    const activeLi = e.currentTarget.querySelector("li.active");

  if(!e.target.isEqualNode(activeLi)){
    e.target.classList.add("active");
    activeLi.classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
        <a href="#home">
            <span class="logo">
                Ernesto Dovizioso
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <a href="#home"><li class="active">home</li></a>
            <a href="#chisono"><li>chi sono</li></a>
            <a href="#servizi"><li>servizi</li></a>
            <a href="#gallery"><li>galleria</li></a>
            <a href="#contatti"><li>contatti</li></a>
        </ul>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- this is invisible untill the hb menu il clicked -->
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#home"><li class="active">home</li></a>
            <a href="#chisono"><li>chi sono</li></a>
            <a href="#servizi"><li>servizi</li></a>
            <a href="#gallery"><li>galleria</li></a>
            <a href="#contatti"><li>contatti</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```